# Synchronizing development PostgreSQL database on local machine

Tags: python, django, windows, git, postgresql

I developed a Django website in Linux, learning Django and git along the way; pushed the source files to Bitbucket.

I'm now in Windows and wanted to see if I could figure out how to work on the project from Windows (just to practice with version control). I did the following:

1. installed python (3.4) installed virtualenv,virtualenvwrapper-win
2. installed PostgreSQL from the windows installer on their website
3. installed psycopg2 from a .whl file because pip was insisting I don't
   have c++
4. installed git using the windows installer from their website
5. cloned bitbucket repository using git
6. create a virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper, installed dependencies
   from requirements.txt (except for psycopg2 which I had to install
   manually)

now I'm a bit confused about the database, do I need to create a new one? how do I synchronize with the local database I created already in linux? is the database part of the version control?

I know that sqlite has a .sqlite file, but postgresql seems to work a bit differently.

EDIT:
I recreated the database and the user in windows, but how do I make sure the information with the Database synchronizes with wherever i'm developing

Comment: You'll need to have a server running. I used pgAdmin III to get mine going. After that, so long as your `settings.py` has the correct database settings,  `manage.py migrate` should be able to take care of the set up.

Comment: but I'm still developing locally, where will the server run?

Comment: In step 2, you installed PostgreSQL on Windows. IIRC, it comes with pgAdmin III, which can be used to launch a local server.

Comment: Let me maybe make myself a bit clearer, I now have 2 different databases one on my ubuntu postgresql and one on my windows postgresql. these are development databases, how can I synchronize them. ( I can't keep the windows one runnning because I'm dual booting windows and ubuntu)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you wanted the data itself to synchronize.. you'll probably want to use fixtures for passing data back and forth. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixtures can be used to move data between databases.

[From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/)

> A fixture is a collection of data that Django knows how to import into
>   a database. The most straightforward way of creating a fixture if
>   you’ve already  got some data is to use the `manage.py dumpdata`
>   command.

--

> Loading data is easy: just call `manage.py loaddata <fixturename>`,
>   where  is the name of the fixture file you’ve created.
>   Each time you run loaddata, the data will be read from the fixture and
>   re-loaded into the database. Note this means that if you change one of
>   the rows created by a fixture and then run loaddata again, you’ll wipe
>   out any changes you’ve made.

Comment: Is it ok to dump my data into git version control and then load it when I pull?

Comment: I don't see why not. Git sure beats a flash drive!